# turn string separated by spaces to arraylist of integers in one line

Tags: java, string, arraylist, int, java-stream

Say I have the String `"5 12 4"`. I'd like to turn that into an `ArrayList` of Integers containing 5,12 and 4 in a single functional line.

I feel there should be a way to do this by combining `split(" ")`, turning it into a `stream`, using `mapToInt(s->Integers.parseInt(s))` and `collect(Collectors.toList())`. Something like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> nextLine = Arrays.stream(inputLine.split(" "))
.mapToInt(s->Integer.parseInt(s))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But that does not work, because `mapToInt` give me `int`s instead of `Integer`s.

I know how to do it using a loop. I would like a way to do it in a single stream operation if it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Integer#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-). Note you should use `Stream#map` and not `Steam#mapToInt` though:

```
List<Integer> nextLine = 
    Arrays.stream(inputLine.split(" "))
          .map(Integer::valueOf)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Yes this works, thank you. I'll accept this as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 3):

`mapToInt` returns an `IntStream` and you cannot accumulate primitive elements into a `ArrayList<T>` therefore you can utilise the `map` operation which would yield a `Stream<Integer>` and then you can accumulate the elements into a `ArrayList<T>`.

That said, even if you change `.mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))` to 
`.map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))` your code still will not compile as the receiver type for the result is of type `ArrayList<Integer>` whereas the `collect` terminal operation will return a `List<Integer>` in this specific case.

Therefore to solve the remaining issue you can either have the receiver type as `List<Integer>`  or leave the receiver type as is and then do `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));` for the reduction operation yielding a specific List implementation.

Another variant to the already posted answer would be:

```
ArrayList<Integer> resultSet =
       Pattern.compile(" ")
              .splitAsStream(inputLine)
              .map(Integer::valueOf)
              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: The variant has the advantage that it doesn't create an intermediate array that you won't use anyways. +1

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner right, and you could also use `\\s`

Comment: @Eugene `String.split` also supports `"\\s"`.